# When are times when it is preferable to copy-and-paste code, slightly changing it, instead of using something like composition?

Tags: class, design-patterns, copy-paste, composition

I have heard design patterns and reducing duplicated code can be very helpful for maintainability, I would like to know when it is preferable to simply copy-and-paste code from one part of a codebase to another and change it slightly instead of using something like composition or some design pattern that avoids this situation?

I also would love to learn about how common this strategy of copying-and-pasting code and changing it slightly is across the industry? Is this common to see at many developer jobs? Also, when does it become preferable to use a different approach?

Comment: Don't copy-paste. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: This is asking for opinions not factual answer, so here goes:. DRY is often a good idea, and very good for things like enumerations, magic constants, rules.  If it's just :code to "do something" like manipulating the contents of an edit box, then trying to define an "edit box manipulation class" that works for several different use cases can  sometimes make the code harder to maintain instead of easier.  And sometimes it *does* make sense to do the extra work for that class.  It's fuzzy.

Comment: At work we used Microsoft's MFC for one application, but found it kept getting in the way of customization that we needed for special cases.  Frameworks (or single shared classes / code) save time for many problems, but can be a straightjacket  when you need to color outside the lines.

Comment: One famous counterpoint to DRY states that [duplication is cheaper than the wrong abstraction](https://sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking!

When you design your application, your goal is to make some code independent from other to protect it from changes by removing dependencies.

For example, if you use one `enum` in two classes which solve different problems and **change for different reasons**, that's problematic, cause if it's necessary to add a new possible value for the first class, it's necessary to change the second class. And potentially it can't handle this value, so the only way to deal with it is to throw an exception with description like "unsupported type of smth".

So if there is some code that is identical **at this moment**, but **the reasons to change are different**, please, duplicate it into different functions or classes to see how it helps with maintainability and parallel developing.

Secondly, **please, do not use any scripts for code manipulating**. At my job I'm developing the implementation of PKCS11 standard. Its C interface has many many different return codes, object attributes and so on. There are so many that my colleagues wrote numerous macros to generate corresponding exceptions and classes for our C++ code. And thats terrific! I literally getting lost in that code that don't even exist before building stage. My smart IDE is constantly depressed, cause it can't help me at all. And the most important thing that I won't risk to change any, cause I don't know how it works (they are pretty complicated), so the maintainability is 0% at my point of view. I would spend days researching the implementation instead of just writing new C++ code in seconds.